# Do Chemists "discover," "invent," or "create" things?

Tags: terminology

I am an ESL teacher, and am designing an activity to teach my engineering students the differences between the words "invention," "discovery," "innovation," and "creation," words that are often confusing for non-native speakers (and as I'm finding out, native speakers.)

I have looked on the internet for usage and it seems to be all over the map: Nobel either invented dynamite, created it, or discovered it, and Teflon was called a discovery.

In my view, physical laws are discovered, as are molecules, fundamental particles, and forces because they already exist naturally.  Teflon cannot be said to be discovered because it does not exist naturally; neither does DDT and thousands of other molecules and compounds.  Is there a plant that produces nitrous oxide?

Based on the usage of "creation" I feel that this word more aptly describes the "process" of chemistry.  Teflon was created, not discovered or invented.

As chemists what usage do you prefer?  Do you prefer the use of inventor, creator, or discoverer?  If there are multiple answers can you help me see why you choose that word?

Comment: If you would like to distinguish between those terms, then *define* them first. Currently I don't see any definitions in your post.

Comment: well, I would like to see how you talk about this without my influence, or saying what I think the words mean.  I want to see what's natural in your word.  I understand context makes a difference.

Comment: You already know that chemists use these words interchangeably. Oxford Dictionary mentions all these terms (invent, create, innovate, discover) as synonyms; Merriam-Webster Dictionary lists two of them you're making the biggest distinction between (discover and invent) as synonyms.

Comment: And I don't think context makes much difference here, it is all about definitions. You said that you teach your students the differences between these words. I ask you what these differences are that you're trying to teach? You obviously have your own definitions for these terms (since you stress the differences between them) and I would like to hear them.

Comment: I'm writing the activity now, based on having these questions come up before and having seen them taught incorrectly in material students brought to class.  Beethoven didn't invent his 9th symphony but they thought that was OK.  To me it seems better to say Nobel created / invented dynamite because he used existing methods and compounds to make something new that didn't exist before...it wasn't part of "mother nature" so he couldn't discover it.   But I'm not a chemist so perhaps in your field it's ok to use the word discover like this  or you define it differently in your profession.

Comment: Well, see, in my opinion it is perfectly fine to say that Nobel discovered dynamite as well. I don't get what problem you have out there. One of the definitions of *discover* from the Oxford Dictionary is "1.2 Be the first to find or observe (a place, substance, or scientific phenomenon)".

Comment: ok, so it seems as chemist you use the word "discover," regardless of whether it was there or not.  This helps.  Let's see what the consensus is on this...if there is one...if not that helps me to help my students.  Thank you.

Comment: However, I don't agree that this is primarily opinion-based. Could the flagger state their opinion more elaborately?

Comment: This seems like it might be suitable for the English Language StackExchange.

Comment: Yes but that area is not frequented by chemists...I don't want guesses and maybes but people in the field.

Comment: Yeah, engineers go both ways on this and it's almost a matter of philosophy. Some are platonic (we didn't invent chairs, we discovered them!) while others, like myself, use discovery to mean that we didn't design it ourselves, we observed it and then (maybe) found a way to duplicate it.

Answer (score 1):

- [discover](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discover?s=t)
- [invent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/invent?s=t)
- [create](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/create?s=t)
- [innovate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/innovate?s=t)

Create is totally weird with chemistry, you can create item, but substance?

Innovate is more about improving something existing.

This leaves us with discover and invent, which in case of chemistry seems to me almost equivalent. For "invent" I would imagine targeted effort towards a new substance with desired properties, whereas "discover" evokes more trial-and-error approach.

Comment: Ok so it seems that in trying to make something new, other unexpected things can happen which are called discoveries...so if a chemist were trying to make X and failed but Y happened and was useful you would call this a discovery...like Nylon...?